# Listview cells are not clickable

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom list adapter that populates a listview.
I am trying to get each item in the listview to be clickable. When clicked, I want the app to load another activity and populate it with the proper data. The data comes from a java list of `listing.java`.

I can't seem to get it to respond to clicks, here is what I've tried so far:

```
//this is in the onCreate method
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listingsAdapter = new ListingsAdapter(this,  mylistings);
    listview.setAdapter(listingsAdapter);
```

here is my first attempt (this was just to get toast working, but it didn't work)

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        };
    });
```

I have also tried this:

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HomeScreenActivity.this, DetailedViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        };
    });
```

Help would be appreciated. Let me know if I should post my adapter as well!

Here is the adaptor:

```
public class ListingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    List<Listing> listings;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListingsAdapter(Context context, List<Listing> listings){
        this.context = context;
        this.listings = listings;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {   
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View _localView = convertView;
        if (_localView == null){
            _localView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_cell, parent, false);
        }
        TextView text1 = (TextView) _localView.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) _localView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);;
        Listing listing = listings.get(position);
        text1.setText(listing.getTitle());
        text2.setText(listing.getAddress());
        return _localView;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listings.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0){
        return listings.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }
}
```

this is the main_cell.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dp"
android:background="#CC7C43"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstline"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I am recovering from a severe hangover and I just remembered that I promised to elaborate on the link I posted - disregard the link!

You should add the following piece of code to your ListingsAdapter:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{
    return true;
}
```

And you should edit the `RelativeLayout` in your `main_cell.xml` from

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="#CC7C43"
    android:longClickable="true">
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="#CC7C43">
```

This works, I have tested it.

Comment: very much appreciated haha, let me see what I can do

Comment: sooo you wanna elaborate? :p

Comment: I thank you for helping me out, but unfortunately this didn't manage to work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to edit main_cell.xml also. Remove android:longClickable="true" from the RelativeLayout

Comment: I have already done this, just updated my post to what it looks like right now

Comment: Yeah but now you have set the RelativeLayout to be focusable and clickable. It must not, because that will catch the click event and prevent it from firing on the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize local instance of View:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View _localView = convertView;
    if (_localView == null){
        _localView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_cell, parent, false);
    }
    TextView text1 = (TextView) _localView.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) _localView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);;
    Listing listing = listings.get(position);
    text1.setText(listing.getTitle());
    text2.setText(listing.getAddress());
    return _localView;
}
```

**UPD**:
Also modify other necessary methods in your adapter class, because you need to get id of an item clicked for using it in onItemClick method:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listings.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}
```

as an example. Hope this will help you.

Comment: would I do this in the activity or the on create method?

Comment: @user2886057 in your `ListingsAdapter` class. Just make a local object and handle it instead of argument of method.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't fix it

Comment: @user2886057 try to not make listview(in onCreate) and view(in arguments of onItemClick) final.

Comment: where should I make the listview and view in that case?

Comment: @user2886057 in the same places as earlier, just without final

Comment: @user2886057 also I've updated some code in my answer, check it out

Comment: thank you so much I will try this first thing tomorrow

Comment: so I added the code to the adaptor, still no luck, do I get rid of the return null from the getItem method?

Comment: @user2886057 I don't know :D. It depends on your code. What have I written above is an example of 2 methods in your adapter. If your listing has simple indexes(hope so!), this code should be right. Read more [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) about adapter interface